# How to change fontsize within a longtable using revtex4-2?

Tags: longtable, fontsize, revtex

I would like to change the font size within a `longtable` using the `revtex` document class. Could you please help me how to reach this goal? It is not a problem if the solution requires modifications in certain style files for this purpose. My MWE is as follows:

```
    \documentclass{revtex4-2}

    \usepackage{longtable}

    \begin{document}
    
    {\huge
    \begin{longtable}{lll}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f
    \end{longtable}}
    
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual advice with publisher's classes is not to alter the styling. But revtex has a hook to normalise the font used for tables (not just longtable) so you could redefine it (perhaps).

[image]

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}

    \usepackage{longtable}

    \begin{document}


text

    {\makeatletter
\renewcommand\table@hook{\Huge}
\makeatother
    \begin{longtable}{lll}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f
    \end{longtable}}
    
    \end{document}
```